# Why the compiler is ignoring the command \noindent in my code?

Tags: captions, line-breaking, paragraphs

I am trying to remove the indentation at the beginning of the paragraphs after figures and tables in my thesis, but the compiler seems to ignore my `\noindent` command. Could anyone guess why?

Thanks

Code attached...

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}

\usepackage{multirow,multicol,makecell,booktabs}

\usepackage{color, soul}

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing

\tolerance=1

\emergencystretch=\maxdimen

\hyphenpenalty=10000

\hbadness=10000

\usepackage[round,colon,comma, authoryear, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{yhmath}

\usepackage{commath}

\usepackage{framed}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true} 

\title{\ttitle} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]

\caption{A generic picture.}

\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Penguins.jpg}

\end{figure}

\noindent Now I want to start a new line. But there is always indentation. How to delete this indentation?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the document class file `Thesis.cls` available online? If so, where?

Comment: you are using a non standard class Thesis that we don't have so hard to see what you get, but you should never have `\noindent` in a latex document in anycase. Can you reproduce the problem using `article` class? also use `example-image` as the image as that is generally available for this use.

Comment: @Mico: Apparently it is the one and only, unique 'Thesis' class everybody uses for her/his thesis. It is the GUT ... the grand unified thesis ;-)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the hints! Yes, I think the issue is in the Thesis class (available here https://github.com/ethan-nelson/aos_thesis_template/blob/master/Thesis.cls)... If I use article, the \noindent command works well.

Comment: I just downloaded the file `Thesis.cls`, and your sample code runs fine with it, i.e., `\noindent` works exactly as expected: The paragraph that follows starts without paragraphi indentation.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Not only is it a GUT, it probably also promises students that it will write their theses for them, while they sleep...

Comment: @Mico: Self - modifying code then? ;-) I prefer IT (Instant Thesis), just pour water over it and it will write itself ;-)

Comment: @user149644: A thesis that is stored under a directory named 'blob' does not make you suspicious? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions...I was trying to avoid changing the class now but it looks like I won't have any other options :-(

Answer (score 3):

The class used sets `\parindent` to 0pt so there indented and unindented paragraphs will appear the same

https://github.com/ethan-nelson/aos_thesis_template/blob/master/Thesis.cls#L53

Note however you should never start a paragraph with `\indent` or `\noindent` in LaTeX, the indentation of paragraphs is decided (as here) by the document class.

In particular figures (even when used with `H`) are logically not part of the document flow they are insertions that are fitted in where convenient, and so you should not think of the following text as being after the figure, logically it follows the text that preceded the figure, and (in document classes that indent paragraphs) it can be indented or not indented as usual by preceding it with a blank line. (Note that the figure environment itself doesn't end the paragraph or even a line a normal floating figure enviornment can be used at any point even between two words in a sentence and it will not force a new paragraph or indentation.